# Can I put all Pardot custom fields in a single text area?

Tags: custom-field, pardot

We have lots of custom fields in Pardot and they seem to change reasonably frequently.

Our CRM users want to be able to see these custom fields, but we don't want to have to create a custom field in SF for each one. There are lots of them, coverage is patchy, and the frequency of changes looks like a maintenance headache.

Is there a way to sync all Pardot fields with a single (long) text area? I'm thinking this would be in the format of:

```
Key1 : Value1
Key2 : Value2
```

I would be comfortable writing some Apex to do this, but I've no idea how I'd hook it into the process. I guess I don't know enough about how the connector works.

Is this possible? How would I go about this?

Answer (score 0):

This wouldn't be best practise and could cause problems with the field syncing with Pardot. 
Each field is individually synced and the sync is evoked if there a data change in either Salesforce or Pardot.

Recommended reading on how the syncing works:
https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=pardot_prospect_syncing_between_pardot_and_salesforce.htm&type=0